# How can I display a desired date into a Wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress, date, shortcode

I'm trying to find a way to choose a date and display it into a Wordpress page.
Simply put, that's the way this may operate:

1. One or several pages are input a shortcode or a PHP code via PHP insert
2. An operator/webmaster chooses a date from let's say a calendar or drop down
3. This date (formatted) shows into the pages that have the shortcode/PHP code

I do not want automatic or current date which I can do with this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/shortcode-for-current-date/).
Can anybody help achieve this with a plugin or a PHP snippet?

Comment: Use the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) to create your date field on a custom options page. Use shortcode to display value with `get_option()` wherever you like.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks !! But maybe I should have say I'm not a developper. I just build websites using WP, themes, plugins and graphics. My only coding skill is to simply read or alter a html/php code. Can you help more with an example I would try to understand and adapt please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display a custom date field in `Settings->Reading`:

```
function wpse_52414489_custom_date() {
// Add the section to reading settings so we can add our
// fields to it
 add_settings_section(
    'eg_custom_settings',
    'My custom settings',
    '',
    'reading'
 );

// Add the field with the names and function to use for our new
// settings, put it in our new section
 add_settings_field(
    'eg_custom_date',
    'My custom date',
    'eg_custom_date_callback',
    'reading',
    'eg_custom_settings'
 );

// Register our setting so that $_POST handling is done for us and
// our callback function just has to echo the <input>
 register_setting( 'reading', 'eg_custom_date' );
} 

function eg_custom_date_callback() {
 echo '<input name="eg_custom_date" id="eg_custom_date" type="date" value="' . get_option( 'eg_custom_date' ) . '" class="code" /> Explanation text';
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_52414489_custom_date' );
```

Add your shortcode (**EDIT**: custom date format):

```
add_filter( 'init', function() {

 add_shortcode( 'my-custom-date', function() {

    return date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime( get_option( 'eg_custom_date' ) ) );

 });

});
```

Usage:

```
[my-custom-date]
```

Output:

```
2018-09-18
```

Comment: Thanks Michael !!!! I guessed this should be put into my theme's functions.php file, so I did using Code Snippets plugin. Everything is working like a charm into Admin Settings->Reading!! Just to ask if it is possible: 1- To format date to display in french (i.e "21/09/2018") and, 2-To have the Custom Date section display in a new WP dashboard menu or into the Main Dashboard (where there are Dashboard Widgets)? I aim to allow a User to acces it via his Admin menu (I customized it via Admin Menu Editor and Webmaster Role plugins). Many thanks again!

Comment: I updated my answer to return a formatted date. I don't think you should create a new top level menu item for every little option; it clutters the backend and makes it more confusing. If you still want to go ahead, there's a code example in the Codex (Example #2): https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Comment: Great!! Working fine. I wanted to put this section apart from Settings->Reading because I hided the Settings section to one custom user role via Menu Editor Pro plugin. So I left him with only Dashboard and a Popup plugin menu. Maybe I should try to make it work in a secured WP dedicated page on frontend...Anyway, many thanks Michael!!

Comment: I solved the issue by simply escalating the user role so he has the Settings->Reading menu. Not so elegant, but this workaround did the trick. I'll play with the codex tutos later.